# How do I create a dynamic make that depends on what arguments I give it?

Tags: c++, makefile

Unfortunately this is a very simplistic question but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm just getting back into c++ programming and figure I'd retrain my rusty skills with some project euler questions. I was planning on quickly doing the first 10 tonight but ran into a problem before I started with the `makefile` (somewhat embarrassing I know).

To the point. I created a directory structure like so:

```
 ✗ tree
.
├── bin
├── inc
├── Makefile
├── obj
└── src
    └── 1.cpp
```

My thinking was that I would create a bunch of separate files in `src` and compile them to `bin` but I have been unable to figure out how to do that. (Is a makefile a bad fit for this? I assumed it would be sufficient).

I thought I would be able to call it with syntax like so:

```
make 1
```

which would compile `bin/1` and `obj/1.o` from `src/1.cpp`.

My attempt so far is like so:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -std=c11
OBJDIR=obj
SRCDIR=src
BINDIR=bin

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)


clean:
        rm -f $(BINDIR)/* $(OBJDIR)/*
```

But this results in:

```
✗ make 1
make: *** No rule to make target '1'.  Stop.
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious and am tempted to resort to a bash script but that feels like cheating and not using the right tool for the job. I'm guessing the problem is that I want to call Make on different files.

Comment: Does `make obj/1.o` work?  You haven't provided any rules related to the `bin/` directory.

Comment: @BenVoigt ahh, it does work, I guess I misunderstood the syntax, I was thinking doing make `1.cpp` would then append the `SRCDIR` and output it to the `OBJDIR`. I was trying to get the object file part done first and then move onto the next bit (which I couldn't figure out). Is there a way for me to have the file be constructed with just `make 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another rule to build the binaries:

```
$(BINDIR)/%: $(OBJDIR)/%.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) # you don't actually need that line!
```

And then one shortcut rule:

```
TARGETS=$(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,%,$(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp))

$(TARGETS): %: $(BINDIR)/%
.PHONY: $(TARGETS)
```

Which allows you to say `make 1` instead of `make bin/1`.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much, I now understand the syntax better for the bindir, I can't however get the `make 1` to work. it just says: `make: Nothing to be done for '1'.` it'll work with `make bin/1`

Comment: @MikeH-R: Yes, you were right. Apparently the `%` pattern was too generic. I updated the second rule. It works on my system. Give it a shot.  Note however, that this assumes that every cpp file in src is a standalone main-file. If you have more involved programs this assumption will break very quickly and you will require more sophisticated rules.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now, and will definitely suffice for my project euler makefile (and helps me understand the format better).